# Copying files always show dialog menu for override

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, samba

I have problem on Windows 10 client side. I want copy file from Windows local disc to Samba share, but i always get dialog menu for override file, but destination folder is empty [no invisible files].

I think it should be some Windows option, because some users [different computer] from our environment do not have this kind of problem.

Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include some screen-shot of this **_"dialog menu"_**  to the post, please?